# Xampp - mysql doesn't return all records

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I'm working on a university project and I have to create a web site which uses a mysql database.

I've started using XAMPP but I found out that when I send a query from the web page not all the records are shown.

The web page should show all books of a library, I've loaded 39 records but the server answers only with 32.

This is the query that I've sent:

```
SELECT titolo, autore FROM libro WHERE 1 ORDER BY libro ASC
```

I have this problem from the web page, but if I do the same query from command line the server returns all records.

Here the php script which asks the server:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","","","biblioteca");
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Connessione fallita (". $mysqli->connect_errno.")".$mysqli->connect_error;
}

//query per recupero di tutti il libri disponibili
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT titolo, autore, genere, disponibilita, codLibro FROM libro WHERE 1 ORDER BY titolo ASC") or die ("Query fallita".$mysqli->error);

//visualizzazione di tutti gli elementi dell'arrray
$count = 1;
print "<br>";
foreach($result as $value){
    foreach($value as $attrib){
        //recupero singoli attributi della tabella 'libro' e li stampo
        $row = $result->fetch_row();

        print $count.". ";
        print " ".$row[0]. " - ".$row[1]." - ".$row[2]." - ";

        //se è disponibile inserisco immagine
        if($row[3]==1)
        {
            print "<a href=\"prenota.php?cod=".$row[4]."&user=". $_GET['user']. "\"><img name=\"prenota\" title=\"Effettua la                   prenotazione\" src=\"/img/ok.png\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\"/></a>";
            print "<br>";
        }else{
            print "<img src=\"/img/no.jpeg\" height=\"25\" width=\"25\"/>";
            print "<br>";
        }
        print "<br>";
        $count = $count +1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach loops are not correct, single loop is enough, it should be:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    //recupero singoli attributi della tabella 'libro' e li stampo

    print $count.". ";
    print " ".$row[0]. " - ".$row[1]." - ".$row[2]." - ";
    ...
}
```

Also, much better for readability and manageability is to use [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and then column names as indexes `$row['titolo']`.

Answer (score 0):

check it out

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","","","biblioteca");
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Connessione fallita (". $mysqli->connect_errno.")".$mysqli->connect_error;
}

//query per recupero di tutti il libri disponibili
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT titolo, autore, genere, disponibilita, codLibro FROM libro ORDER BY titolo ASC") or die ("Query fallita".$mysqli->error);

//visualizzazione di tutti gli elementi dell'arrray
$count = 1;
print "<br>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['username'] . '<br />';
    //recupero singoli attributi della tabella 'libro' e li stampo
    print $count.". ";
    print " ".$row["titolo"]. " - ".$row["autore"]." - ".$row["genere"]." - ";

    if($row["disponibilita"]==1){
        print "<a href=\"prenota.php?cod=".$row["doLibro"]."&user=". $_GET['user']. "\"><img name=\"prenota\" title=\"Effettua la                   prenotazione\" src=\"/img/ok.png\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\"/></a>";
        print "<br>";
    }else{
        print "<img src=\"/img/no.jpeg\" height=\"25\" width=\"25\"/>";
        print "<br>";
    }
    print "<br>";
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: This does not affect the result at all.